# Soln for U-Boot Compilation error with myir board?

Tags: u-boot

I'm using the MYD-Y6ULX-HMI series boards supports the Linux kernel version 4.1.15, and provided with rich hardware and software resource. They recommend to use Ubuntu 16.04 64bit distribution. For more details about the devkit
-> http://www.myirtech.com/list.asp?id=602
-> http://d.myirtech.com/MYD-Y6ULX-HMI/

By referring their usermanual,
(1) Installed virtualBox with Ubuntu 16.04 64bit distribution

(2) Installed software package and made the working directory in root.

(3) Installed Yocto toolchain:gcc version 5.3.0(GCC) - for driver(metatoolchain)

After installation sourced the env file:

```
source /opt/myir-imx6ulx-fb/4.1.15-2.0.1/environment-setup-cortexa7hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi
```

and checked the compiler version:

```
arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc --version
```

(4) Now trying to make u-boot config and compiling it with that able to generate config file but facing issue while compiling it,

(a) Sourced the metaToolChain
(b) Entered the U-bootsource file directory
(c) given sudo make distclean
(d) Exported the env variables CROSS_COMPILER and ARCH
(e) sudo make 
the core board of one i'm using is MYC-Y6ULY2-356N256D-50-C
(f) sudo make
But cant able to compile. Can any one please help on this to solve the issue?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idfYN.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idfYN.png)

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `sudo` here.  It's a bad practice all around, but specifically in this case the environment from the user isn't passed to sudo, so `CROSS_COMPILE` is unset, so that's why you see that error.